# JavaScript + Canvas

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Gente estou estudando canvas com HTML5 então que me surgiu o seguinte problema, quando eu importo o arquivo externo do JavaScript dentro da tag "head" ele não reconhece. Só quando eu coloco dentor do body.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

if (canvas.getContext) {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
  context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);

  context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
  context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
}
```

Quando eu coloco:

```
<!-- JavaScript externo -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Dentro da tag head ele não funciona, só no fim do corpo(body)

Answer (score 6):

Isso acontece porque quando o browser lê o `head` e corre o script, o `document.body` ainda não existe. Ou seja `document.getElementById('myCanvas');` só pode correr depois de o browser ter lido esse HTML.

Podes deixar ficar no `head` **mas** dentro de uma callback para só correr quando o DOM estiver pronto, ou como estás a fazer no `body`.

Para deixar no `head`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);

      context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
      context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
    }
}
```